# How to convert a text into integer using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

Is there any **Selenium IDE command** which can help to read a text and convert it in to integer ?

Comment: Check out the documentation and/or post your attempts at solving your issue

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Big No. There is no as such command. You can perform this operation in any language.